# Why does the orbital angular momentum quantum number $l=0$ not violate the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, lie-algebra, observables

The total magnitude of angular momentum is specified by the $\hat{L}$ operator, and the components of angular momentum are given by the $\hat{L}_x$, $\hat{L}_y$, $\hat{L}_z$ operators. $\hat{L}$ commutes with just one of the component operators (conventionally chosen as $z$), however, each of the component operators are complimentary. Since the $\hat{L}_z$ operator is conventionally chosen, the $x$- and $y$- components of angular momentum are completely uncertain.

So my question is: when the quantum number $l = 0$, is the uncertainty rule broken? There is no magnitude of angular momentum or $z$-component of angular momentum ($L = 0$; $L_z = 0$), therefore, all three components of angular momentum are known ($L_x = 0$, $L_y = 0$, $L_z = 0$). Am I conceptually misunderstanding something?

Comment: Have you tried to actually write down the uncertainty principle for a state with $l=0$?

Comment: ? On the state $|\ell = 0, m=0\rangle$ the expectation values of all six $L_i$ , $L_i^2$ vanish, so Robertsn's uncertainty relation is saturated. What exactly are you asking? How did you define your misbegotten operator $\hat L$? You are making bizarre statements there. What is your question?

Comment: You may find the answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210464/the-uncertainty-in-angular-momentum?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You say, "the x- and y- components of angular momentum are completely uncertain." This sounds like you have in mind the canonical commutations relations such as $[x,p_x]=i\hbar$. Under those commutation relations, it's true that if one variable has zero uncertainty, the other has infinite uncertainty. But the angular momentum operators you're talking about don't obey those particular commutation relations.